# Data protection still works after deleting all keys from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, data-protection

Please consider this code:

```
ServiceProvider services;
private void InitializeKeys()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
    serviceCollection.AddDataProtection().SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(14)).PersistKeysToDbContext<MyContext>();
    services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    services.GetDataProtector("MyClass.v1").Protect("payload");
}
```

and `MyContext`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {

    }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; } = null!;


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=ThisIsMyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True");
    }
}
```

after I run my project one key was built successfully in database:

[image]

and protection was did successfully:

[image]

Code for protection:

```
var Provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("MyClass.v1");
IDataProtector _protector = Provider.CreateProtector("MyClass.v1");
txtEncryptResult.Text = _protector.Protect(txtEncryptValue.Text);
```

This is when the case becomes interesting that I stopped the running application and I deleted all keys from database.

[image]

Now I want to decrypt protected value that I got from previous step and it still works:

[image]

Code for unprotect:

```
var Provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("MyClass.v1");
IDataProtector _protector = Provider.CreateProtector("MyClass.v1");
txtDecryptResult.Text = _protector.Unprotect(txtDecryptValue.Text);
```

Why does it work whereas all keys were deleted??

Thanks

---

**Edit 1)**

Based on @Dai answer, I updated my codes and it works well:

```
var Provider = services.GetDataProtector("MyClass.v1");
IDataProtector _protector = Provider.CreateProtector("MyClass.v1");
txtEncryptResult.Text = _protector.Protect(txtEncryptValue.Text);
```

Comment: Your `InitializeKeys` method doesn't do anything useful... You're not meant to instantiate your own `ServicesCollection` - you get that from your `IHostBuilder`.

Comment: _"Why does it work whereas all keys were deleted??"_ - it works because it has been using the default keys - it never used your custom keys in the first place because you weren't using `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` correctly.

Comment: @Dai: That's because I have created a `Windows Application Project` and I simulated `Service Collection`.

Comment: Don't "simulate" anything. You should be using a real `IHost`; otherwise you're wasting our time as well as your own by doing this.

Comment: @Dai Could you show me how can I use my custom keys from database please? Thanks

Comment: It's 03:53am here, I don't have the time to give you a complete example, sorry.

Comment: @Dai: I'll wait for you to wake up ;).

Comment: You're underestimating how long it will take for me to recover from my inevitable hangover - I just had 3 shots of 68% ABV absinthe

Comment: @Dai but amidst this hangover you recognize my problem.

Comment: Do you have a git repo I can clone with the source-code for this to repro? There's a lot of moving-parts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("MyClass.v1");
```

Your code is using the `static class DataProtectionProvider`, which is just a utility class with factory methods for getting a *quick-and-dirty* `IDataProtectionProvider` instance **without** using (or participating in) a DI container - so the `DataProtectionProvider.Create` method will not use your `ServiceCollection` from `InitializeKeys` *at all*.

...and [this is mentioned in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for `DataProtectionProvider`:

> Use these methods when not using dependency injection to provide the service to the application.

As per the documentation, the various `DataProtectionProvider.Create` overloads will return an `IDataProtectionProvider` that uses a (unspecified) local filesystem location to store the keys: <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> Contains factory methods for creating an `IDataProtectionProvider` **where keys are stored at a particular location on the file system**.

---

If you want to *always* get an `IDataProtectionProvider` that *always* uses the same configuration/options as set in your `InitializeKeys` method then you'll need to ensure you **only** ever call `services.GetDataProtector("MyClass.v1")` and **never** call the static `DataProtectionProvider.Create` methods.

---

When I run it in Linqpad on my computer, `DataProtectionProvider.Create(String)` returns a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector` which uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager` which saves keys to `C:\Users\$me\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys` - but this behaviour is machine-specific (the internal `DefaultKeyStorageDirectories.GetKeyStorageDirectoryImpl()` method will return different directories based on your computer's OS and certain environment variables) - so you shouldn't depend on any assumptions you make about it.

Remember that this library is still meant for use only with ASP.NET Core - I'm honestly surprised it works at all in a desktop program.